# Update from 2.0 to 2.1: Class for <label> gets lost on it's way

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I just updated **symfony2** from *2.0.16* to *2.1.2* and now I've got the problem, that my class for the label isn't added anymore.

In the Twig-template I include the field like this:

```html
<div class="row{% if form_errors(form.object) %} _error{% endif %}">
    {{ form_label(form.object, null, { 'attr': {'class': '_hint'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.object, { 'attr': {'class': 'c6'} }) }}
</div>
```

And my extension of the default form layout looks like this:

```html
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' with field_label as base_field_label %}

{% block field_label %}
    {{ block('base_field_label') }}

    {% if attr.class is defined and '_hint' == attr.class %}
        <div>
            some
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The strange thing is, that the `attr.class` value is set, as the `<div>` gets rendered. But the class is not added to the `<label>` anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. you should overwrite a `form_label` block instead of `field_label` because `field_label` is [deprecated](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L321)
2. You should use a `label_attr` array instead of `attr`, ie:

   ```
   {% if label_attr.class is defined and '_hint' == label_attr.class %}
   ```

Comment: +1 Worked like a charm and thanks for adding that info about the deprecated parts.